# How can I run a thread in a scheduled job, outside of "__main__"?

Tags: python, multithreading, schedule

I want to do something like that:

```
def foo(tickers):
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    for ticker in tickers:
        loop.run_in_executor(executor, get_data,ticker)


schedule.every().minute.at(":00").do(foo)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

I'm using the "schedule" package to execute a function foo at a precise time of the minute.
But right now, I can only execute the threaded function with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        foo(tickers)
```

How can I have it executed every minute with that `schedule` object?

EDIT: Here is my modified code:

```
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)

def foo(tickers):
    args = (ticker for ticker in tickers)
    executor.map(get_data,args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo(tickers)
```

Comment: You need to call  `schedule.run_pending()`.  And why are you using `asyncio` instead of just creating the pool and submitting the tasks with, for example, `map`. And why are you creating the pool repeatedly instead of re-using the same pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment to your question. Here is an example of what I mean using the built-in `sched.scheduler` class. But you can  the `schedule` module instead with little change:

```py
import multiprocessing
from sched import scheduler

def worker(x):
    print(x, flush=True)

def foo():
    pool.map(worker, (1,2))

def main():
    global pool
    import time

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    s = scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    s.enter(delay=1, priority=1, action=foo)
    s.enter(delay=2, priority=1, action=foo)
    s.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```